# How do I use the if else statement to check if the user has inputted a valid entry in relation to array list index?

Tags: java

Im trying to create a modify method that allows the user to see their entry that was previously inputted and be able to re input that entry thus replacing the entry. However, when I try to code the if else statement that checks if their input is a valid index the program claims that no matter what you input its incorrect. please advise.

```
public static void Modify() 
{

readelements(); 

System.out.println("Enter the desired # of the entry you would like to modify"); 

int Mod = Cons.nextInt(); 


if (Mod != Notes.size())
{
System.out.println("You've selected an invalid entry!\n");
}
else {

System.out.println(Notes.get(Mod));
Notes.remove(Mod); 
System.out.println("Please copy and paste your entry for re-entry");
String NewMod = Cons.next(); 
Notes.add(Mod, NewMod); 

}

Execute.Instruct();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `n-`sized array, valid indices are `0..n-1`. Same applies to Lists.

So for instance, if your list has 4 elements, valid indices are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Your input validation condition should become

```
if (Mod < 0 || Mod >= Notes.size()) {
  // complain
} else {
  // index is good
}
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for your explanation, it helped me understand the problem and also gave me future knowledge that can help me further along.

Comment: if it isn't too much trouble would you be able to help with another problem i am currently having.. . inside the else statement portion i am trying to read the new user input that is going to replace the index that is currently holding the text that is to be modified. However, whatever the user puts only the first word is read and the rest is discarded, i have tried using the nextLine() Statement but it ends up just printing the instructions back and doesn't allow the user to input anything. Any ideas??